# Custom checkbox wont toggle when click and drag on label

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my custom checkbox.

If you click on a checkbox element, move the mouse cursor and then release the click inside the checkbox area, the checkbox is checked.

However, if you do the same on a custom checkbox (here, a div inside a label), the checkbox isn't checked.

It's a problem because if you want to quickly check a checkbox, you may move the mouse after pressing the button of the mouse and before releasing it, thus not toggling the checkbox.

The user is obligated to click without moving the mouse.

I know I can use JS to emulate a checkbox with a div, but I want the HTML to be semantically correct, so: Is it possible to fix it without js?

Here's the code :

```css
/* 1. Hide the checkbox */

      .hidden {
        /* https://zellwk.com/blog/hide-content-accessibly/ */
        border: 0;
        clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: auto;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

/* 2. Use a label to retrieve the click event */

      label {
        /* not used directly to prevent the bug in firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608180 */
        pointer-events: none;
        display: inline-flex;
      }

      label > input {
        /*usefull for testing only*/
        pointer-events : all;
      }

      label > .customCheckbox {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;

        --size:200px;
        width: var(--size);
        height: var(--size);
        font-size: calc(var(--size)/2);
        pointer-events: all;
      }

      label > .customCheckbox::selection{
      /* prevent highliting the text within the custom checkbox */
          background: none;
      }

      label > .customCheckbox:after {
        
        z-index: -1;
        content: "✔";
        display: inline-flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: calc(var(--size)/4);
        border: solid black calc(var(--size)/10);
      }

      label > input:not(:checked) + div.customCheckbox:after {
        background:#0000;
        content: "\a0";
      }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>   

<label >
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"/>
        <div class="customCheckbox"></div>
</label >
```

I need the checkbox to be inside the label because I can't use the "for" attribute.

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT: for those wondering, here's the js solution (not ideal but since I can't do it in CSS, it's better than nothing) :

```
let checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("customCheckbox");

    for(let i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (e)=>{handleMouseOverCheckbox(e)})
      checkboxes[i].addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{handleMouseOverCheckbox(e)})
    }

    function handleMouseOverCheckbox(e) {
      e.srcElement.previousElementSibling.disabled = "true";
      if (e.buttons == 1) {
        e.srcElement.previousElementSibling.checked= !e.srcElement.previousElementSibling.checked;
      }}
```

EDIT 2 : Here's the best solution I could come up with, thanks to 
 @zer00ne

[codepen.io/DesignThinkerer/pen/bGVBLjM](http://codepen.io/DesignThinkerer/pen/bGVBLjM)

Comment: You said, *"I need the checkbox to be inside the label because I can't use the "for" attribute."* Why? Also you are you using a `<div>` ? As for as pure CSS interactive behavior are concerned `<div>` has no features nor could it be given any via CSS. The `<div>` is your problem and it's completely unnecessary (actually useless).

Comment: Because in the case of a dynamic list of checkboxes, if we want to link a checkbox to a label (to make a custom checkbox for example), we either need to dynamically generate id OR include the checkbox in the label to be linked to.

 I want my code to be as performant as possible and keep the JS to a strict minimum, but in this case, I think I'm out of luck ..

Also, I need to use an element inside the label rather than the label itself because in some cases, on firefox, the click event is not fired when rapidly clicking the label (please see my comments in the code).

Comment: I see the problem with `[for]` attribute. As for the `<div>` I don't see (I read the bug report and there was no suggestion of such a fix). What is `.previousElementSibling.disabled` referring to? Another checkbox? `e.buttons` for the left click? `e.srcElement` is deprecated form of `e.target`. This behavior that you are worried about doesn't look like anything posted so far is close to a working solution TBH.

Comment: In the js code that I've posted, we listen to the click on the div inside the label. 

.previousElementSibling.disabled refer to the input element before the div. We need to disable it to prevent the user to be able to toggle the checkbox when the js already does it.

I wish there was a way to target a sibling with a css selector but I don't think it's possible (efficiently) in vanilla JS :/

Yes, e.buttons allow to check for which mouse button is pressed.
.target doesn't work in IE IIRC.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61334654/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checkbox within a label is no problem. The problem arises when that checkbox is altered for the sake of accessibility instead of complete removal using `display: none`. When an interactive element like an input or button exists in the DOM, it will still be a factor no matter how its hidden unless `display: none` is applied.

In the **O**riginal **P**ost the checkbox is almost impossible to click due to its 0px height and 1px width and yet when the div is clicked, the checkbox is clicked... sometimes not. Normally if the label was able to detect a click, that click would trigger a click event to the nested checkbox as well. In the OP code that's not happening because the label has `pointer-events: none`.

So the div is getting clicked and by some magical miracle this gains features that would not normally be attributed to it? Divs are not interactive they cannot affect elements that are not nested within themselves (i.e. like the checkbox that sits before the div). Nope, the div is useless, its the checkbox itself that's getting clicked due to the fact it is the only element within the inert label that gains focus by default. Gaining focus on an input doesn't necessarily guarantee a click event -- matter of fact a focus event selects an element and a click event sets an element as active. So what happens when a user double-clicks or moves the mouse quickly before the next click clears a label? Undesirable behavior as described in OP.

In the following demo, the checkboxes are hidden as per OP (also set width and height to 0) and removed `pointer-events: none` from the label and added it to the checkboxes. In this setup the label gains focus and click events and the click event will trigger the checkbox. The checkbox having been isolated from any extra clicks due to `pointer-events: none` and `z-index: -1` should behave as expected.

As proof of concept I have added some JavaScript to demonstrate said code stability. The two event handlers are for demonstration purposes. The JS does not facilitate, stabilize, or modify performance of the HTML/CSS behavior.

1. On any change event on a checkbox (via label) will trigger `function changeHandler()` to gather all the values of the checked checkboxes and display them in an output.

   - If there's a checkmark in a box and there's a value displayed that corresponds to said checked checkbox, then it successfully passes as valid behavior.
2. Clicking `button.show` will trigger `function clickHandler()` to toggle the `.reveal` class to each checkbox.

   - While clicking rapidly observe that the revealed checkboxes are checked and its corresponding custom label is checked as well. Also notice that the value should also be displayed as well.

---

#### BTW

- > *"....target doesn't work in IE IIRC"*

  `event.target` is the standard property to use in every modern browser. `event.srcElement` is a deprecated property used by IE which is almost entirely unsupported.
- > `pointer-events: all` assigned to `input` and `.customCheckbox`

  The value `all` applies to SVG only. Only the values of `none` and `auto` are relevant to HTML. `auto` is default.

---

#### Demo

I cannot reproduce the described behavior except in the code provided in OP. If you can reproduce that behavior on my demo, please record a short video of it and post that and the machine/device, OS, and browsers (I will assume everything is reasonably up to date).

```js
const main = document.forms.main;

main.onchange = checkHandler;

function checkHandler(e) {
  const fc = this.elements;
  const chx = [...fc.hidden];
  const ui = e.target;

  if (ui.matches('.hidden')) {
    let text = chx.flatMap(c => c.checked ? [c.value] : []);
    fc.view.value = '';
    fc.view.value = text.join(', ');
  }
}

main.onclick = clickHandler

function clickHandler(e) {
  const fc = this.elements;
  const chx = [...fc.hidden];
  const ui = e.target;

  if (ui.matches('button.show')) {
    chx.forEach(c => c.classList.toggle('reveal'));
  }
}
```

```css
:root,
body {
  --size: 10rem;
  font: 400 small-caps 2vw/1.5 Times;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  font: inherit;
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  max-height: min-content;
  margin: 10px;
  border: calc(var(--size) / 20) solid #000;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.view {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 35ch;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12ch;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mask {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: solid black calc(var(--size) / 10);
  border-radius: calc(var(--size) / 4);
  font-size: calc(var(--size) * 0.8);
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -1.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.hidden {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.reveal {
  z-index: 0;
  top: -24px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon::after {
  content: attr(data-blank);
}

.hidden:checked+.icon::after {
  content: attr(data-check);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang='en'>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name='main'>
    <fieldset name='display' class='display'>
      <output name='view' class='view'></output>
      <button name='show' class='show' type='button'>Show</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name='display' class='display'>
      <label name='mask' class='mask'>
    <input name='hidden' class="hidden" type="checkbox" value='Check I'>
    <fieldset name='icon' class='icon' data-check='✔' data-blank=' '></fieldset>
  </label>


      <label name='mask' class='mask'>
    <input name='hidden' class="hidden" type="checkbox" value='Check II'>
    <fieldset name='icon' class='icon' data-check='✔' data-blank=' '></fieldset>
  </label>


      <label name='mask' class='mask'>
    <input name='hidden' class="hidden" type="checkbox" value='Check III'>
    <fieldset name='icon' class='icon' data-check='✔' data-blank=' '></fieldset>
  </label>


      <label name='mask' class='mask'>
    <input name='hidden' class="hidden" type="checkbox" value='Check IV'>
    <fieldset name='icon' class='icon' data-check='✔' data-blank=' '></fieldset>
  </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! I disagree with some of the things you say in this post, but maybe I'm the one being wrong. 

You're right, the checkbox receives the focus when it's not in display:none.

However, when label is set to pointer-events:none and the div to pointer-events:all  

- or auto, you're right "all" is for svg but this still works, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events - 

the checkbox doesn't receive focus but still get the click event trough the div because of the event capture/bubble phases.

Comment: The label doesn't get focus nor click, which is perfect because it prevents undesirable behavior (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=559506).

If I double click (while the mouse is not moving), this works fine.

Here's a demo where I test this: https://codepen.io/DesignThinkerer/pen/ZEbByaW

Another reason for why the div is needed is because we can't customize the label based on it's checkbox state with css.

Comment: It will be possible when :has will be implemented, but for now we need to use an element inside the label. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

And we can't use pseudo-elements on the input (except in chrome and opera) because it's not defined in the W3C spec.

So we need to use an element, for example, a div.

Comment: Also, I have the same issue with your code. I will post a video. I'm on W10, I use firefox developer edition 76.0b6.

Comment: @ThéophileDesmedt click the show button so that the checkboxes are showing then test it. BTW if the div is `e.target` then the input isn't in the event chain at all. Input and div are siblings -- they do not share the same path.

Comment: https://youtu.be/940ojt9K3Eg

I show at the start of the video the expected behavior. Weirdly, the default checkbox does work but not the checkboxes in your code. I think it's because of the label.

Comment: okay so I'm beginning to think there is no way to do that without directly clicking on the checkbox, so maybe the best solution is to use opacity:0 on the input, give it a 100% width and height and position it in absolute relative to it's container (label or not).
The checkbox is still accessible and we can put whatever we want in the container to stylise it.

Comment: yup, seems about right : https://codepen.io/DesignThinkerer/pen/bGVBLjM

What do you think of this solution ?

Comment: I agree the input filling the label is better. Accessibility couldn't be any better than that, but keep in mind that the label intercepts the event first since it is the parent. I'm thinking the same thing about the need for the label at all...no keep it because it's an accessibility issue if you don't have it. I installed Firefox developer ed. and see what your saying, not so with regular edition.  Win 10 BTW.  Maybe FF dev being 12 weeks ahead of FF reg releases?

Comment: You said, *"Weirdly, the default checkbox does work but not the checkboxes in your code.*" The checkboxes in my code have `pointer-events: none` and are buried at `z-index: -1` (label is parent and at `z-index: 2` and input sibling is at `z-index: 1`) with 0x0 dimensions and out of normal document flow using `position: absolute`. Basically it's as close as `display: none` as its gonna get, but as I said before its presence still has influence. Going big and bold is better.

Comment: _keep it because it's an accessibility issue if you don't have it_

Right. I think that's what I'll do!
Thanks again for your help  :)

Comment: I would've never considered actually using the checkbox directly and actually showing it rather than hiding it. Thank you, sir.